# powershell SharePoint - Can't get past confirmation dialog when trying to rename site

Tags: powershell, sharepoint

I have approx... 1200 Sites that all are now being assigned to different Hub sites in SharePoint.  Do to this the client would like all the URLS to be prefixed with the hub name.  I know the command works fine if I am willing to sit and click confirm every single site (NO THANKS).  I have tried multiple things so far. I have set the $ConfirmPreference var to "none", "low" etc etc... I have also tried what the command specifically has a switch for and that is -confirm:$false.  However, no matter what I do I keep getting the confirmation box.  Here is the code. I'm sure I'm just missing something stupid but any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
$creds = Import-Clixml -Path "mypath\file.xml"
Connect-SPOService -url "SharePoint Admin Site" -Credential $creds

Start-SPOSiteRename -Identity "SomeSite" -NewSiteUrl "SomeNewSite" -Confirm:$false
```

Answer (score 1):

[image]
When I test with -confirm:$false,there is no confirmation box showing.

The type of parameter confirm is **SwitchParameter**,you could know more about it [here](https://powershell.org/forums/topic/understanding-switch-parameters/).

Comment: I'm at loss here then as my code is the same as yours and it still prompts me every time.  I read about the switch parameter but that didn't really help me.  Am I missing something here?